# Finding the size of the documents that are stored inside the Couchbase server

Tags: json, serialization, couchbase

I have two types of documents, JSON and BinaryDocument, that are being stored in the buckets. I am in need of evaluating the sizes of the documents that are **stored inside the Couchbase server**. That is, I don't want to retrieve the documents through views, use `stringify` operation on JSON documents to find it's length and I don't want to use `decodeBase64` operation on BinaryDocument to find it's length. That gives me the decompressed file size.

In short, I want to know how much each document takes up space inside the server. Or at least, the **average space taken by the JSON documents** and the **average space taken by the binary documents**. This is to know how efficiently the Couchbase server compresses the documents while storing them inside.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: A solution is suggested in http://blog.couchbase.com/calculating-average-document-size-documents-stored-couchbase

Comment: @TAM This is exactly what I didn't want to do. I already saw this blog. Here it queries on the documents and decompresses them. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `couch_dbdump` command (in `/opt/couchbase/bin`) to dump the couchstore files on disk - that will show you the "real" size and compressed size for each document.

Assuming your JSON and binary documents have predicable keys, you could then filter by the particular document types and see what numbers you want.

Comment: This not very convenient when the total size is many TBs though....